# Pandas loop groupby

Tags: pandas, filter, merge

I have a data
df1

```
 Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
 12     10   R1    0.1
 12     10   R2    0.1
 12      8   R3    0.6
 11      4   R4    0.2
 12      10  R5    0.4
 11      4   R6    0.1
```

df2 is a subset of df1

```
col 1 col 2 count 
12     10     3
12     8      1
11     4      2
```

I want the output of rows matching col1 & col2 of df2 with df1.and thereby automate for each and every combination in df2.

For Combination of 12 ,10  in df2 i want matching rows in df1

```
col 1 col2 col3 col 4 
12     10   R1   0.1  
12     10   R2   0.1
12     10   R5   0.4
```

similarly i want to create a loop for next combination in df2 (12,8)

```
Col 1 col 2  col 3  col 4 
12     8      R3     0.6
```

similarly i want to create a loop for next combination in df2 (11,4)

```
Col 1 col 2  col 3  col 4 
11     4      R4     0.2
11     4      R6     0.1
```

i have tried this df3=df1[(df1.Col1 == 12.0)&(df1.Col2 == 10)] but want to automate it without mentioning the combination

Comment: How to get a count of rows in each case

Answer (score 0):

I think you second `DataFrame` is not necessary, only loop by each combinations of unique values in `Col1` and `Col2` columns:

```
for i, g in df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2']):
    print (i)
    print (g)
```

If want more dynamic solution for dictionry of DataFrame:

```
d = {f'{i[0]}_{i[1]}':g for i, g in df1.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])}
print (d)
{'11_4':    Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4
3    11     4   R4   0.2
5    11     4   R6   0.1, '12_8':    Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4
2    12     8   R3   0.6, '12_10':    Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4
0    12    10   R1   0.1
1    12    10   R2   0.1
4    12    10   R5   0.4}

print (d['11_4'])
   Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4
3    11     4   R4   0.2
5    11     4   R6   0.1
```

Comment: @ansev - Be free close

Comment: @ansev - I think so also, check previous question of OP.